# solve logarithmic equation without numerical methods

Tags: logarithms, closed-form

Is there algebraic method to solve following equation for $x$:
$$
    a x + b \ln x + c = 0
$$
with $a , b , c$ constants without using numerical methods and ln means natural logarithm.

Comment: What do you consider algebraic or numerical for that fact? If you are talking a purely algebraic ie without lambert then no as you have transcendental function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
ax+b\ln(x)+c=0\\
ax+b\ln\left(\frac abx\right)+c-b\ln\left(\frac ab\right)=0\\
\frac abx+\ln\left(\frac abx\right)+\frac cb-\ln\left(\frac ab\right)=0\\
{(\frac{a}{b})x}\,e^{{(\frac{a}{b})x}}=(\frac{a}{b})\,e^{-\frac{c}{b}}
$$
The [Lambert-W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) is the inverse of $xe^x$. 
$\Rightarrow$
$$
\\{(\frac{a}{b})x}=\mathrm{W}\left((\frac{a}{b})e^{\frac{-c}{b}}\right)
$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$
x=(\frac{b}{a})\mathrm{W}\left((\frac{a}{b})e^{\frac{-c}{b}}\right)
$$

Comment: it's my first time to know Lambert-W function now i know value of

(a/b)*e^(-c/b)
how to know value of

w(a/b*e^(-c/b))

Comment: @EngMohamedSamy $u=W(x)$ which gives $x=ue^u$   please put the green 'V' on the answer